# Google Wallet Multiple cart item example code

Tags: android-pay

I have been looking around on the google wallet tutorials and though there is an example site that you can browse on your phone with multiple items, there is no code sample showing how you pay for multiple items in a cart. What I want to know is how do I call the process that pays for the total cart items. The example I have seen only shows one item with a buy now button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function purchase(){
 goog.payments.inapp.buy({
  'jwt'     : {{ generated_jwt }},
  'success' : function() {console.log("success")},
  'failure' : function() {console.log("failure")}
 });
}
</script>

<button onclick="purchase();"><b>Buy Now</b></button>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The "idea" is that Google Wallet is involved in the payment part (only) - _access_ to Wallet information in `Instant Buy` or _purchase_ itself in `Digital Goods`. So that means "just the money" part - you provide/pre-calculate the amount needed for payment (for x cart items). "Cart Items" (one on more) is something you manage in your own web/app. Hth...

Comment: Could you provide an example code in which the onclick is not calling a  'jwt' : {{ generated_jwt }}, which is really referencing a specific product?